# Trying to build for Windows Store in VS2013, "unable to verify your developer account"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, winjs

I'm trying to build a WinJS app in Visual Studio 2013. I usually don't get this error but once in a while I do. When I try to build and it asks me to sign in, it sends me an approval code to my phone. Once past that step, I get this error:

"Visual Studio was unable to verify your developer account. Either the store is unavailable . Either the store is unavailable or an unexpected network error has ocurred"

It's been happening all morning.

Comment: The same thread on here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d3876e12-04c5-467c-8f66-e0d0d372d956/visual-studio-was-unable-to-verify-your-developer-account-either-the-store-is-unavailable-either?forum=wpsubmit

Comment: A comment by E. Nokso-Koivisto says that VS2013 support for building 8.1 apps is entirely dropped. I haven't seen this documented anywhere but this would put a spanner in my plans. How can i get this confirmed?

Comment: Our project is a Windows 8.0 app and Visual Studio 2015 does not support those. We are not ready to drop the support for 8.0!